# Adding SVG file to CloudPages

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, cloudpage, svg-icon

I'm trying to add an SVG file to a CloudPage in Marketing Cloud. Though the file type is enabled in our MC Account, SF support says we need to create an AMPscript in order to include these files.

I guess it shouldn't be a very complex script to develop but I have no clue where to begin...

Comment: SVGs are images, so have you uploaded them to Content Builder as an asset?  Once you've done that, you should have an image URL that you can include in your code.  No AMPscript required.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same requirement and according to my findings,

- For SVGs URL is not providing in the Content Builder
- AMPscript *ContentImagebyKey* and *ContentImagebyID* are working fine for other
  image types but not work for SVG images

I was able to add SVG images to cloud page with svg tag instead of using img tag with URL,

```
    <svg width="200px" height="100px">
     ...
    </svg>
```

Visit https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/

This is not the best option but this is the only way I found.