# SVG file type in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, url, content-builder, svg

Has Marketing Cloud stopped support for SVG files? We need to migrate content from an old MC tenant to a new one, including some SVG files.
On the old tenant, the SVG files come with a URL from where the asset is directly accessible:
[image: URL for SVG file on old MC tenant]

When I download the file and upload it to the new MC tenant, the URL is not available:
[image: No URL available on new MC tenant]

Do we need to enable SVG files somewhere in the settings or are they simply not supported anymore (as they were apparently in 2017)?
I haven't found anything helpful so far, except for an entry where someone [faces the same issue](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/252747/42912), but without resolving it for the URL.
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: That file type can be enabled by SF Support: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/212437/5202